# Set cookie doesn't work for cross origin requests vercel

Tags: authentication, cookies, http-headers, cross-domain, vercel

i'm using Vercel and currently I'm trying to implement authorization with firebase.
But I have problem that my backend is not setting the cookie. I went into the Network tab and can see the request has a 200 status and the set-cookie value is present.

Headers
[image: Headers]
Backend set cookie

[image: backend set cookie]

Front-end post request

[image: Front-end post request]

My front-end is deployed on - localhost:3000

My vercel serverless backend is on - localhost:4000

I also set headers in vercel.json but that doesn't work either.

```
"headers": [
{
  "source": "(.*)",
  "headers": [
    { "key": "Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "value": "http://localhost:3000" },
    { "key": "Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "value": "true" },
    { "key": "Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "value": "GET,OPTIONS,PATCH,DELETE,POST,PUT" },
    { "key": "Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "value": "X-CSRF-Token, X-Requested-With, Accept, Accept-Version, Content-Length, Content-MD5, Content-Type, Date, X-Api-Version" }
  ]
}
```

Whats funny is that when i open localhost:4000/api/auth/sign-in with already entered credentials, cookie is set.

Comment: My guess it that it's setting the cookie for the wrong domain. Anyway I'd advise you to edit your setup. Create a new proxy server and proxy all `/api/*` requests to vercel port and the rest to the frontend port. Otherwise get ready for a headache.